# what are all requirements for run the visual studio 2010 vb projects

Tags: vb.net, deployment, vb.net-2010

I developed the project in visual studio 2010. That exe file is not supported for other PC's.
which dotnetframework to be installed? other than dotnetframework is there any other requirements needed?

Comment: What is your build Target `x86`, `x64` or `AsAny` also what Framework are you targeting. You can find out that information by going into your `Project Poperties --> Compile -->` click the advanced Compiler Settings button and looking at the bottom of the resulting form.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not the CPU type you specified during compiling (x86 vs x64 CPU).  If you compiled in 64-bit and a user only has a 32-bit processor (x86), your code won't run.

The .Net Framework should work on any PC-based system, but be sure to include it in your deployment or setup package.  (you can provide Excel, .NET Framework, and many other packages with your package.)

You should also try to find out what error messages your users are receiving -- which will point you in the right direction.